# Issues with Jmeter GET request. It returns 401 error and shows unable to authorise

Tags: get, jmeter, session-cookies, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I am trying to send a GET request in JMETER. But it's not going through and giving me the following error:

```
Thread Name: End to End Insight Box test 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-12-07 17:07:28 EST
Load time: 16
Connect Time: 2
Latency: 15
Size in bytes: 28787
Headers size in bytes: 336
Body size in bytes: 28451
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 28451
ETag: W/"6f23-0bLnx7HfhP7SCnvUxqCu0w"
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AaQNcuFY1rAJsD0zK8kzVaUPvpog4nFXP.PD2fB8x8XLvFogGSe6l3l%2BHKQ0Sa0KQKf0qt4zE208I; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Wed, 07 Dec 2016 22:07:28 GMT
Connection: close


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

In the request:

```
[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: close
content-type: application/json
Host: 192.168.100.194:3001
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)
```

For this GET request the user needs to login. So I wrote a python script to login using OS process Sampler before this GET request. Still I am having the issue

Comment: try by adding HTTP Cookie Manager.

Comment: I did it, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You most probably forgot to add either a Session cookie or a Token in headers or in parameter.

I'd suggest trying to record the call with Http Test script recorder element (just use the Templates menu and select recording, then start the Recorder)

This will create for you the Http Sampler with the parameters or headers required.
You will just have to make it dynamic then by extracting it from the response it appeared in and injecting it the the request that is failing.